# How we can create installation file of any project in Qt?

Tags: qt, qt4, installation

I want to create installation file for my project so that i can install it where i want to run
my program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there is [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) for Windows and PackageMaker for Mac. Qt doesn't have installer primitives as such. Oh and there's the cross-platform [BitRock](http://installbuilder.bitrock.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Also try [CPack](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/CMake%3aPackaging_With_CPack). It comes with CMake and creates packages for all the desktop platforms Qt  runs on.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [installer-framework](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-labs/installer-framework/) which is used for Qt SDK. It also includes an on-line updater.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, there is also [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php).